# Multiple Form posts to multiple PHP scripts inside 1 document

Tags: php

I'm trying to Post a form:

```
<form role="form" method="post">
    <select name="inputStore">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Show items</button>
</form>
```

to a PHP script which generates another form in it. Now im trying to post the PHP form to another PHP script inside of the current document.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>

<form>First form posts to PHP</form>
<?php First PHP which generates another Form ?>
<form>Form which got generated from the first PHP post. This form should POST to the second PHP</form>
<?php Second PHP ?>
</body>

</html>
```

How would I get this working? The PHP scripts have to stay at their positions. Cant wrap those two inside one PHP Tag

Comment: You don't need multiple form, you can do it in simple jquery click functions itself. Do you want to do that ?

Comment: Well the first PHP generates some overview of items through a XML file. which should post it to another PHP Script to uplaod the items to an account. Problem is i cant controll the posts. And it shouldnt be Js peoples shouldnt see the post, which comes from the second PHP

Comment: Yes, you can do that in a simple ajax call.

Comment: Will the post be hidden? For example like a PHP curl post?

Comment: You mean, you try to say you don't want to refresh the page ?

Comment: I dont want peoples to see the post parameters. Cause they contain parameters which peoples shouldnt see.

Comment: Even if you do via normal `$_POST` people can able to  see your param right !

Comment: Ohhh i can use ajax to post the parameters to the PHP. Got it :o

Comment: You want any help in it ?

Comment: Writing answer for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the thing you wanted to do

Here i am just sending the value to another and just retuning the same to the parent file.

**index.php** (that is in the front)

```
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<form role="form" method="post">
    <select name="inputStore" onchange="getval(this);">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
</form>
<div id='result'>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getval(sel) {
    var datas =sel.value;
    console.log(datas);
       $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url : "response.php",
         data: { 
        'selected': datas, 
    },
        success : function(data)
        {
        console.log(data);
        $("#result").html(data);
        }
    },"json");

    }
</script>
```

**response.php** That will process your request

```
<?php
$value = $_POST['selected'];
echo 'This is sent from server '.$value.' - End';
?>
```

### Update :

**(As the questioner wants to see output for 2 inputs at same time )**

Here is the Front File :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<form role="form" method="post">
    <select name="inputStore" id="inputStore" >
        <option value="stud">Male Hottie</option>
        <option value="babe">Female Hottie</option>
    </select>
    <select name="inputStoretwo" id="inputStoretwo">
        <option value="20037336">Artizans</option>
                                                        <option value="20080134">Bwabies!</option>
                                                        <option value="20097365">Crave Mart</option>
                                                        <option value="20099998">David &amp; Goliath</option>
                                                        <option value="20098166">Domo</option>
                                                        <option value="20101926">Emily the Strange</option>
                                                        <option value="20098167">Garfield</option>
                                                        <option value="26">Jetsetter</option>
                                                        <option value="3">Like Dat</option>
                                                        <option value="21">Paris Hilton</option>
                                                        <option value="19">Rocawear</option>
                                                        <option value="10">ShoeBuy</option>
                                                        <option value="20100198">Skelanimals</option>
                                                        <option value="20096121">SW&amp;TH</option>
                                                        <option value="1">The Castle</option>
                                                        <option value="4">The Lair</option>
                                                        <option value="923">The Mix</option>
                                                        <option value="20098121">The Powerpuff Girls</option>
                                                        <option value="5">The Surf Shop</option>
                                                        <option value="20076231">Tie The Knot</option>
                                                        <option value="20099224">Tokidoki</option>
                                                        <option value="2">University Club</option>
                                                        <option value="6">Z Avenue</option>
                                                        <option value="20099506">Z's Greetings</option>
                                                        <option value="20">Snoop Dog</option>
    </select>
</form>
<button>Pass the value</button>

<div id='result'>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$("button").click(function(){
   var first = $("#inputStore option:selected").text();
   var second = $("#inputStoretwo option:selected").text();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url : "response.php",
         data: { 
        'firstvalue': first, 
        'secondvalue': second, 
    },
        success : function(data)
        {
        console.log(data);
        $("#result").html(data);
        }
    },"json");
});
</script>
```

and here is the **response file :**

```
<?php
$first = $_POST['firstvalue'];
$second = $_POST['secondvalue'];
echo 'This is first value : '.$first.'<br> and this is the second value : '.$second;
?>
```

Comment: Do you want to send the output that is choosed from the select box ? or ok with this ?

Comment: Thats completely okay :)

Comment: Lets say i have 2 select items ?

Comment: You need to see the value of two drop down's ?

Comment: It starts with a site where peoples select 2 dropdown menues, then a menu shows up with the items. After that they select a item and post it to the php

Comment: You want to display to the items on the second menu to generated on basis they choose first menu or send the values of both menu to another file and return it ?

Comment: Both select items have to be send to the php and this php document will return the items to the document

Comment: Thanks, is it normal that it disapears fast again? Example see: http://dev.pr0b.com/item/

Comment: The content returned by backend file ?

Comment: I realized when i uploaded it without my own html. Something in my Html refreshes the site

Comment: Cool, just replace the button with `<input type="button" id="fire" value="Show Items">` and `$("button").click(function(){` to  `$("#fire").click(function(){`